# Ubuntu: How do the md devices get assembled at bootup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, mdadm, initrd

How do the `md` devices get assembled at bootup in Ubuntu? Is `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` truly the relevant factor here?

My `mdadm.conf` is sound and I checked that while I was in the rescue CD environment. When running `mdadm -A --scan` it finds and assigns the device names as desired. The `mdadm.conf` contains `AUTO -all` to take out all automatism from assembling the arrays.

What I need to do is to be able to auto-assemble the `md` devices as outlined in `mdadm.conf` at boot time or that when assembling it honors the `super-minor` value for the 0.9 array and the `name` (apparently `<hostname>:<super-minor>`) for the 1.2 arrays and does the right thing without `mdadm.conf`. What puzzle piece am I missing?

---

I have the following problem. There are two `md` devices with RAID1 (`md0` and `md1`) and one with RAID6 (`md2`). I am referring to them by the *desired* device names. `md0` has meta-data version 0.9, the other two have version 1.2. `md0` maps to `/` and the other two are not relevant for *booting*.

The boot drive is GPT partitioned. There is a glue "BIOS Boot Partition" (`sda1`) on it. `grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda` reports success.

- `md0 == sda3 + sdb3`
- `md1 == sda2 + sdb2`
- `md2 == sdc + sdd + sde + sdf + sdg + sdh`
- `sda1` and `sdb1` are "BIOS Boot Partition" each

GRUB2 is happy with the `/boot/grub/devicemap` I gave it and I added `part_gpt`, `raid`, `mdraid09` and `ext2` to the modules to preload in GRUB2.

Since I still had my root volume in the rescue environment, I simply mounted everything and then `chroot`ed into it:

```
mkdir /target
mount /dev/md0 /target
mount -o bind /dev /target/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /target/dev/pts
mount -o bind /sys /target/sys
mount -o bind /proc /target/proc
chroot /target /bin/bash
```

From there I reset the `super-minor` on `md0` (with meta-data 0.9) and the `name` on `md1` and `md2`. I also verified that it worked using `mdadm --detail ...`.
Other than that I adjusted `/etc/default/grub`, run `update-grub` and also `grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda` and `grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sdb`.

After that, when booting, I am always dropped into the `initramfs` rescue shell, however, because the root file system could not be mounted. The reason, after checking `/proc/mdstat` appears to be that the respective `md` device doesn't even get assembled and run. Not to mention that the other two (meta-data version 1.2) drives receive a device number somewhere in the 125..127 range.

**Note:** GRUB2 comes up from the boot disk. So at the very least it has been embedded correctly. The issue is the transition from the initial `rootfs` to the proper root file system.

Comment: Don't use `/dev/mdX` for exactly this reason. Use `/dev/md/NAME` instead. That will never change.

Comment: @Patrick: I don't get what you're trying to say. The problem isn't the names per-se. That's more or less cosmetic. The problem *was* that the root volume would not be assembled, therefore not available for boot and hence I couldn't boot. I'm using UUIDs to tell GRUB2 what device is which and I'm using UUIDs in `/etc/fstab`. The setup doesn't *rely* on the names, I still would like them to be that way ;)

Comment: I should have clarified. That was only advised as a resolution to your comment `Not to mention that the other two (meta-data version 1.2) drives receive a device number somewhere in the 125..127 range`. I don't know enough about how ubuntu assembles raid volumes to answer the bigger issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Basic Boot Process

### Grub

1. Grub reads its disk, md, filesystem, etc. code from the MBR.
2. Grub finds its /boot partition, and reads the rest of itself out of it. Including the config, and any modules the config specifies need loading.
3. Grub follows the instructions in the config, which typically tell it to load a kernel and initramfs into memory, and execute the kernel.

There is a fallback mode, for when Grub can't actually read the filesystem—either because there wasn't enough space to embed all that code in the boot record, or because it doesn't know the filesystem or layers under it. In this case, GRUB embeds a list of sectors, and reads code from them. This is *much* less robust, and best avoided. It may even be able to do kernel and initramfs like that (not sure).

### Kernel

The kernel then takes control, and does a lot of basic hardware init. This stage is fairly quick. Next, the kernel unpacks the initramfs to a tmpfs, and looks for a `/init` on that tmpfs. It then executes (in the normal sense, the kernel is fulling running at this point) `/init`. This is, by the way, a plain old shell script.

### Initramfs

You can extract the initramfs by hand by doing something like `mkdir /tmp/foo; cd /tmp/foo; zcat /boot/initrd.img-3.8-trunk-amd64 | cpio -idmv`.

The initramfs is responsible for loading all the drivers, starting udev, and finding the root filesystem. This is the step that is failing for you—it can't find the root filesystem, so it bails out.

Once the initramfs has finished, it has the root filesystem mounted, and hands over control to /sbin/init.

### System boot

At this point, your init takes over—I think Ubuntu is using upstart currently.

## What's Broken

I'm not entirely sure what's broken (part, I confess, because I'm much more familiar with how it works on Debian than Ubuntu, though its similar), but I have a couple of suggestions:

- The initramfs has its own copy of `mdadm.conf`. You may just need to run `update-initramfs -u` to fix it.
- Look at the boot messages. There may be an error. Get rid of 'quiet' and 'splash' and maybe add 'verbose' to your kernel line to actually see them.
- Depending on storage used, you may need to set the rootdelay parameter.
- When you're dumped to the shell prompt, you don't have a lot of commands, but you do have mdadm. Try to figure out what went wrong. If you fix the problem, boot can continue.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found out that I was missing simply one piece. The `initrd` images had not been updated after tinkering with `mdadm.conf`.

So what did I do?

I booted into the Ubuntu Server install CD's rescue system. Chose to execute a shell from the installer environment and *not* to use a root file system. Then (comments prepended with `#`):

```
cat /proc/mdstat
# It showed me md125, md126 and md127
# Stop those:
mdadm -S /dev/md125
mdadm -S /dev/md126
mdadm -S /dev/md127
# Assemble the root volume (meta-data version 0.9)
mdadm -Av --update=super-minor --run /dev/md0 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3
# Assemble the other two arrays, updating the names (meta-data version 1.2)
mdadm -Av --update=name --run /dev/md1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
mdadm -Av --update=name --run /dev/md2 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh
# Check the outcome:
cat /proc/mdstat
# See preferred minor and names:
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
mdadm --detail /dev/md1
mdadm --detail /dev/md2
# All is fine, so proceed ...
# Create directory for the chroot:
mkdir /target
# Mount root volume on it
mount /dev/md0 /target
mount -o bind /dev /target/dev
mount -o bind /proc /target/proc
mount -o bind /sys /target/sys
mount -o bind /dev/pts /target/dev/pts
# Now chroot into it:
chroot /target /bin/bash
# Fix up the GRUB device map to match what 'mdadm --detail' gives as UUID:
nano /boot/grub/devicemap
```

> #### nano
>
> I'm using `nano` because `vim` caused me headaches because of the dumb terminal, literally.
>   You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to quit (will prompt to save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to cut the current line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to paste a cut line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the buffer.

This sounds complicated, but can be done also with a `bash` one-liner (albeit a long one):

```
for i in /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-*; do DEV=$(readlink $i); echo "(${DEV##*/}) $i"; done|sort|tee /boot/grub/devicemap
```

This uses the *current* names of the `md` devices and their UUIDs and creates a `devicemap` for GRUB2's perusal. So assuming the above was done correctly, you should have the correct device names already.

Further on:

```
# Edit the grub config
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Make sure it contains:

```
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt raid mdraid09 ext2"
```

if you have configured your `/` or `/boot` partition to be meta-data version 1.2, use `mdraid1x` instead of `mdraid09`.

Further:

```
# Update the initrd images
update-initramfs -c -k all
```

**This above step was the missing link**. This apparently makes sure that the `mdadm.conf` takes effect on boot.

```
# Install GRUB2 on the two drives eligible for booting, just to be sure
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sdb
# Make the latest config take effect
update-grub
```

After that leave the `chroot` and reboot.